# Adjust top while maintaining bottom position with CSS

Tags: css, word-processor

A website I'm working on now is meant to replicate a document that you could print. There is a header, a body, and a footer. All three elements use CSS to adjust the margins and height of each one.

The footer is 0.5in high and must end at least 0.5in from the bottom of the page, but cannot exceed that. Based on other word processors, if the footer is larger than 0.5in, the footer moves up on the page so that it maintains that 0.5in border.

This means that the body will shrink, so I've set it up (I think) so that a larger footer will shrink the body which is the expected behavior.

However, what I want is a way for the footer to adjust its position on the page so that it is always at least 0.5in from the bottom of the page.

Note I'd like the solution to work for any number of pages for one document, so I can't use fixed positions.

I'm including my demo code which works as long as the height is small enough.

```
<div style="height: 9in;
padding-left: 1in;
padding-right: 1in;
padding-top: 0.5in;
padding-bottom: 0.5in;
background-color: #eee;
margin-top: -0.08in;
margin-left: -0.08in;">
            <div style="height: 0.5in"> Nick 1 </div>
            <div style="max-height: 9in; height: 9in;">I love stuff.</div>
            <div style="min-height: 0.5in; height: 0.5in; margin-top: 0.5in;">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but why don't you use margin-bottom:0.5in?

Comment: Completely unrelated, sorry. You are the first person I've seen who uses `in`. Any particular reason why?

Comment: @user2019515 I was thinking the same thing. And what odd in-line styles. what about this is HTML5 or word-processor related? Anyway, I think you should read up on external style sheets and using em (or at least percentages). To answer what I think is your question, sticky footer.

Comment: @AliBZ, the point is that the bottom stays in the same place, but as the height increases, it pushes the div up.

Comment: @user2019515, I'm trying to generate a page that I can print, so by using inches I can generate a properly formatted page.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE This is just a sample page I'm working on, so that's why I'm not using external style sheets. Word-processor is an odd tag, but since I'm generating a print preview page, I thought that the tag may be helpful. HTML5 goes along with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [CSS sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) technique.

The priciple is this:

- the content has a bottom padding equal to the height of the footer
- the footer uses relative positioning
- the footer has a top margin equal to it's own (negated) height

The result is an overlap of the footer over the padding of the content. Since the sizes match the overlap makes the footer "stick" to where the content ends.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a sticky footer.

The CSS

```
.wrap { 
  min-height:100%;
  margin-bottom: -.4in; /* same as footer */
}
.push, #footer {
  height:.4in;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you use native javascript or jquery CSS is not a programming language but javascript will give you more functionality for testing for the conditions needed ﻿

Comment: I did an a trial with javascript and it turned out to work fairly easily.

` h = $('.header').height();
 f = $('.footer').height();
 $('.footer').css('margin-top', '-'+(f/h)+'in');

`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're looking for can be done with CSS only, at least not until flexbox model is more widely supported. If you're using Chrome 24 or higher you can see the code below in action at http://jsfiddle.net/2late2die/bNJZG/1/

```
.page {
  width:8in;
  height:10.5in;
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
  margin:.5in auto;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.2) 0 0 .1in;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -moz-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.page .body {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -moz-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

It basically sets the body of the page to be a flexbox item that stretches to take up the entire vertical space between header and footer. You still however would need to manage the height of the body yourself, because if it gets more than the space left between header and footer it will overflow.